# Console is flooded by "F/otapreopt_chroot(): No activated com.android.art APEX package."

Tags: android, motorola

After some random time my **Android Studio** console is flooded every second by the following errors:

```
F/otapreopt_chroot(14798): No activated com.android.art APEX package.
F/otapreopt_chroot(14812): No activated com.android.art APEX package.
F/otapreopt_chroot(14825): No activated com.android.art APEX package.
```

I could not trace down, what causes this to start. This problem persists after rebuild and stop/start run. I could also disconnect the phone with no effect. Then at some point the problem suddenly disappears (mostly after disconnecting the phone and wait some time).
I could not find any further information for this yet and have no idea what I should look for. Any ideas?

**Environment:**

- Test device: Motorola moto e20
- Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the problem:

The error occurs, when the **Motorola Update Service** performs a software/security update.
As long as the Android system notification (about the security update) is not clicked/removed and the device stays connected the Android Studio console keeps getting flooded.

**1. Click/acknowledge the Android system update notification**

**2. disconnect and reconnect the device usb**

Now the message does not appear anymore.